# ORMlite how to add Collection<Collection<Double>>?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite, android-database

I have the following Class:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class BodyWeight implements Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, useGetSet = true, columnName = "id")
    private Long id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField
    private double goal;

    @DatabaseField
    private String primaryunit;

    @DatabaseField
    private String secondaryunit;

    @DatabaseField
    private int secondarysize;

    @DatabaseField
    private Collection<Collection<Double>> data;
```

How could I add a list of list of doubles primitives to database? What is the process? Should I create more classes for the List of list of doubles?

Comment: Normally Sqlite don't support List,hashmap,collections so you have to convert it to string and save it in your database.

Comment: *you have to convert it to string and save* ... terrible idea ... It would be better to use additional tables ...

Comment: @Selvin could you give me an idea how could I do that?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/93188

Comment: and how should I add that to my BodyWeight class?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to keep `Collection<Collection<Double>> data` in your class and store it as JSON string in database with using custom persister. Like this

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = MyCustomPersister.class)
Collection<Collection<Double>> data;
```

Where MyCustomPersister should implement `com.j256.ormlite.field.DataPersister` or one of available implementations. Basically just two methods:

```
@Override
public Object resultToSqlArg();
@Override
public Object sqlArgToJava();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How could I add a list of list of doubles primitives to database? What is the process?

This is pretty complex. One way is just to make the type be serializable.

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
private Collection<Collection<Double>> data;
```

That, like @unnamed_b's answer will store it in place as a serialized block of bytes.  This won't work if you have a large number of doubles however.

If you want to store it as objects in another table then you are going to have to define these objects.  Something like:

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private long id;
@ForeignCollectionField
private Collection<DoubleCollection> data;
```

ORMLite only handles straight collections so we need to define the sub-collection:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class DoubleCollection {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private Collection<DoubleWrapper> data;
}
```

If you need to store a collection of doubles then you need to define a wrapper to hold an id and your double value.

```
@DatabaseTable
public class DoubleWrapper {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField
    private double value;
}
```

Comment: I did something exactly like this but it didn't work because that `Collection<Collection<Double>>` comes to me as a JSON format and GsonBuilder doesn't recoqnize the new format `Collection<DoubleCollection>` and crashes.

Comment: Yeah it's sometimes impossible to use the same entity in Json and ORM.   GsonBuilder didn't "crash" i'm sure.  It probably didn't know about the `DoubleCollection` entity.  Is there some way to tell the builder about it @JuLes?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. The thing is that I have a model class named Track which has 10 other object(classes) as fields. Now each of this classes has that `List<List<Double>>` field. The method that converts the JSON is `GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(text, Track.class)` where `text` is the String JSON. Do you know a way to do it better with Gson?